# Fry and steam - which first?

Tags: frying, pork, steaming

Consider potato OR pork cubes of 1-2cm size. I find both delicious when they have steamed inside but a brown crisp outside. I achieve that by frying(in 5mm oil) them but use a lid for a part of the cycle. How can I use the lid so the result, in the case of **meat**, is well done inside and a Maillard crust?

And secondly - when the lid is applied the food starts steaming. However depending on the heat setting it can also continue frying or only steam. Which is better?

---

My experience: If I start off with steaming, the mashy potatoes fall apart later during frying. No idea about meat - sound sane but haven't tried it.

If I start off with frying the crisp prevents any spices from sticking.

No lid - lid - no lid seems to work best for potatoes.

Comment: Is this deep frying or sauteing?

Comment: Note that “healthiest” is certainly off topic here and “tastiest” is very much bordering on subjective.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the same technique will be right for both potatoes and pork, no?